# how to convert timestamp on windows ping -s option to date?

Tags: windows, timestamp, ping

> > ping [SomeIP] **-s 4** -t > ping.log

result of that command is like below.

> > Reply from [SomeIP] : bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=125
> >
> > Timestamp: [HOP] : 83842793 ->
> >
> > ```
> >           [HOP] : 83842793 -> 
> >
> >           [HOP] : 83832797 -> 
> >
> >           [HOP] : 83842793
> > ```

how can i convert this timestamp to datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp you get is number of miliseconds past midnight UTC time. Date is current date.

Conversion from here is simple:

```
time = timestamp /1000

hours = (time / 3600)
minutes = (time / 60) - (hours * 60)
seconds = time mod 60
```

Comment: thanks pal.
im in korea, so i have to 9 hours when i display hours.
reference: http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/UTC

Comment: Yes Korea is UTC+9. If I recall, there is no DST in Korea so you are set :) Just be careful to take in to account the day if it rolls into the next day (locally)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a quick way to convert date/time to timestamp and back, I just came  across [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/utime/kpcibgnngaaabebmcabmkocdokepdaki) and I think it's really great! It's the quickest cross platform method and I use it constantly since it parses plenty of date formats and is really fun nice to use.